# Inserting records into servicenow table using C#.net

Tags: c#

I have a csv containing emp nos and date field. I want to iterate over the csv and insert those records into a service now table using C#.net.
Any pointers will be helpful.

```
public static void CreateRecordsinServiceNow(List<KeyValuePair<string, user_Record>> dt)
 {
   String userID = "";
   string username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceNowUserName"];
   string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceNowPassword"];
   string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceNowUrl"];
   var auth = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(username + ":" +    password));
   try
     {
       //iterate over List for records.. 
       Log("\r\n POST request started");
     }
 }
```

How do i proceed.

Comment: We need more focus - What exactly don't you know how to do? The code you've shared basically does nothing

Answer (score 0):

asumming each line of your csv contain only emp no and a date, this is a code you can try.  I am starting from your own implementation done here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

public static void CreateRecordsinServiceNow(List<KeyValuePair<string, user_Record>> dt)
{
    string username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceNowUserName"];
    string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceNowPassword"];
    string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceNowUrl"];
    var auth = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

    try
    {
        Log("\r\n POST request started");

        // Read CSV file
        string csvFilePath = "sample/path/for/csv/file.csv"; //your actaul csv file here
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(csvFilePath))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] values = line.Split(',');

                // Extract empNo and Date values from CSV columns
                string empNo = values[0];
                string date= values[1];


                // Create a request to insert the record into ServiceNow
                string requestBody = $"{{ \"column1\": \"{empNo}\", \"column2\": \"{date}\" }}";
                string requestUrl = $"{url}/api/now/table/your_table_name"; //replace this with ur actual table name
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);
                request.ContentType = "application/json";

               
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    writer.Write(requestBody);
                }

               
                using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
                    {
                           Log("Record inserted successfully.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Handle error cases
                        Log($"Error inserting record. Status code: {response.StatusCode}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle exceptions
        Log($"Error: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

I would like to help logic issues like these as a support to fellow developers. Please do not hesitate to send me an email explaining your new requirement at gemunu.rohana@hotmail.co.uk I should be able to put some time to it among my other tasks. Kindly share my email with any of your friends needing similar logic support.